# Why does a translation in the horizontal direction affect PointSize?

Tags: graphics

I'm running *Mathematica* 9.0.1 under Mac OS X.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or whether I'm not supposed to apply a `GeometricTransformation` to a list containing graphic primitives and directives:

```
verts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {Cos[60 Degree], Sin[60 Degree]}};
tri = {{PointSize[0.2], Point[verts]}, {Line[verts ~Append~ First@verts]}};
```

Translating purely in the vertical direction works how I expect it to:

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[tri, TranslationTransform[{0, #}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]]
```

[image: vertical translation]

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[tri, TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]]
```

However, if the translation has a horizontal component, then the point size gets messed up, in the sense that it's not compensating for the size of the points with respect to the size of the graphic in the notebook:

[image: horizontal translation]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs of `PointSize[]`:

> The diameter (of the point) is given as a fraction of the total width of the plot.

In other words, it adjusts point sizes *relative* to the width. Since your plot widened after the transformation, it stands to reason that your points should grow in size as well.

To drive the point home, ponder upon the result of

```
{Graphics[{PointSize[0.2], Point[{0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.2], Point[{0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-2, 2}}]}
// GraphicsColumn
```

(I deliberately did not upload the picture of the result, so as not to spoil the surprise. :P )

If you don't want this growth, consider using `AbsolutePointSize[]` instead.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to check the documentation for `PointSize`. I guess I was mistakenly expecting it to behave like the radius of a `Disk[]` object.

Answer (score 6):

In my *Mathematica* work I frequently construct diagram in which I show polygons with their vertices represented by dots. I prefer to use `Disk` to draw the dots rather than `Point` because I feel doing so avoids the problems that can arise from having to specify the point size with either `PointSize` or `AbsolutePointSize`.

Your question illustrates the problem that can arise from using `PointSize`. Now let's look at the problem that can arise from using `AbsolutePointSize`.

```
verts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {Cos[60 Degree], Sin[60 Degree]}};
tri = {{AbsolutePointSize[12],  Point[verts]}, {Line[verts~Append~First@verts]}};
```

The choice of 12pts looks good when the graphic is drawn at the default image size.

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[tri, TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]]
```

[image: Point.1.png]

But look what happens when the image is down-sized by supplying an explicit `ImageSize` option. I think the vertices now look too big relative to the triangles because they *do not* change size.

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[tri, 
  TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]], ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image: Point.2.png]

Because problems can arise with both `PointSize` and `AbsolutePointSize`, I recommend representing vertices in graphics by `Disk` rather than `Point`. I further recommend using `Polygon` rather than `Line` for drawing polygons (the default filling of the polygon is easily removed).

```
vertices = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {Cos[60 Degree], Sin[60 Degree]}};
vertexPts = Disk[#, 0.06] & /@ vertices;
triangle = {Transparent, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[vertices]};

Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{triangle, vertexPts}, 
  TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]]
```

[image: Disk.1.png]

Now if I reduce the image size, the dots representing the shrink proportionally.

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{triangle, vertexPts}, 
  TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]], ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image: Disk.2.png]

You might also consider one more simplification: using `Translate` in place of `GeometricTransformation` and `TranslationTransform`. `Translate` will give simpler code in your particular example and in many similar situations.

```
Graphics[Translate[{triangle, vertexPts}, {#, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]
```

[image: Disk.1.png]

```
Graphics[Translate[{triangle, vertexPts}, {0, # Sin[60 Degree]}] & /@ Range[0, 2]]
```

[image: Disk.3.png]

Comment: One could use `FaceForm[None]` instead of `Transparent` so that only the polygons are affected.

Comment: @J.M. +1 I have always wrapped my polygons in their own `List` along with `Transparent`, so it has never caused a problem for me. But I can see that, in general, using `FaceForm[None]` is cleaner.